# VS Code Debug Cell button disappears arbitrarily in Jupyter Notebook view

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I am developing a Python script in a Jupyter Notebook (ipynb file) in Visual Studio Code.

Arbitrarily, the "**Debug Cell**" run option disappears and I have not found a way yet to debug a specific notebook cell in a different way.
I am just able to run the cell, but there is no way to debug the cell.

[image: No "Debug Cell" option clickable in VS Code]

According to the [VS Code documentation on "Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code - Debug a Jupyter Notebook"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_debug-cell) there should be this arrow visible, which allows to click on "Debug Cell".

[image: Debug Cell image from VS Code Documentation]

After restarting VS Code the Debug option is usually again visible.

What am I doing wrong that this "Debug Cell" option becomes invisible for me or is this probably a bug? Has anyone else noticed this issue yet?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling jupyter and then reinstalling? Or create a new virtual environment to start using jupyter again. Also, is it possible to debug directly using the shortcut keys in the screenshot?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. Sometimes closing and reopening the workbook clears the problem; other times I need to close and reopen VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug in VS Code and is still an [open issue on their GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219) as of writing this answer. (1+ years..)

The suggested workaround is to use 'Developer: Reload Window' from the command palette. It is only marginally faster than restarting VS Code altogether and you will lose workspace variables, remote connections, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is the subject of a bug ticket: [Debug Cell option disappears
#150219](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219).

People have found various workarounds:

- One workaround people have found is to reload the window, which you can do by using the `Developer: Reload Window` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Note that this may cause some state of the Jupyter Notebook to be lost, which makes it a bit non-ideal as a workaround.
- [Another user has found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1690028378) that the issue doesn't happen if they open the Notebook file directory instead of opening a folder containing it as a workspace folder, [and that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1690100408) deleting the project's venv and recreating it caused the issue to no longer happen.
- [Another user found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1693595732) that switching to another venv, the problem didn't happen there, though it still happened in the previous venv.
- [Another user found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1693608877) that removing the "Typing" module from the env helped. [Ex](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1779075096). `%pip uninstall typing -y`.
- [Another user found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1780551696) that the keyboard shortcut to debug the cell still worked for them: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.
- [Another user found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150219#issuecomment-1793825227) that they had the message "*`[IPKernelApp] WARNING | debugpy_stream undefined, debugging will not be enabled`*" in their jupyter-notebook logs, and that installing the `python-debugpy` package fixed the issue.